# React Router v4 - can't access URL parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router v4 and for some reason I can't use URL parameters. Here's my code

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
...
render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
            <Home ...props />
            )} />
          <Route path="/events/:userID?" render={() => (
            <Events ...props/>
          )} />
          <Route path="/patients" render={() => (
            <Patients ...props />
            )} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Events

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Events extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

    };
  }


  render() {

    console.log(this.props.match.params.userID);

    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

I'm trying to set the 'userID' as an optional parameter and render different logic on the Events component depending whether the userID is present or not.

However, when I try to call {this.props.match.params.userID} I always get undefined.

EDIT:

I added the Events component, which is the one I need to send the userID to. When I try to log {this.props.match.params.userID} in the console I get this error: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(can't write comments yet, so I'm writing an answer).

Please provide more information about where you are trying to call `{this.props.match.params.userID}`.

Is it inside one of `Events`, `Patients`, `Home` components?

If yes, according to React Router v4 [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match), the `match` property is "inside" the `props` argument of the `render` function (the function passed in as `render` prop of `Route`).

You are omitting the `props` argument and instead passing in the `props` which are inherited from the parent scope (if any).

Try doing:

```
<Route path="/events/:userID?" render={(props) => (
  <Events ...props/>
)} />
```

Comment: as you've written in your edit - `match` is undefined most probably because you are not passing it to the rendered component.

Please try out my solution

Comment: I think that's the problem. Either the `Route` is not passing the `match`property to the Events component or I'm accessing it incorrectly. I've tried what you suggested but still got the same error

Comment: You were right. I followed your advice and added the parameter as props and it worked. I did something like this: `<Events userID={props.match.params.userID} />`

Comment: You both just saved my .... hours of seeking for a solution once `'create-react-app CLI'` is used. Don't know why, but, precisely, `props.match` don't get through... Also found a solution(?) [here](https://github.com/DavidWells/react-router-tutorial) but did not tested it - seems to address the same CLI problem.